# Injecting component level service into Resolve

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-components

Let's see if I can explain this right.

I have service, let's called it `ServerSocket`. This service handles web socket stuff.

Then at the *component* level, I have various services that extend a base service (We'll call it `BaseDataService`) that use `ServerSocket` to retrieve data. This service is at the *component* level. Meaning:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-management',
  templateUrl: './management.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./management.component.scss'],
  providers: [ManagementService] <-- This is a BaseDataService
})
```

This way a websocket gets created dedicated to this one component.

`ServerSocket` has an observable that is the raw data (text) from the socket, `DataService` subscribes to this.

So far so good.

Now, at one point, my app is going to send a number of queries into the socket, each query has a random token with it. Something like:

`get DKJ39U4 server/3 users`

At some point in the socket, I'll get a response with that token in it so I know the response is for that query. I also am able to done when a `BaseDataService` is done loading as all the queries I've sent out, I've received a response.

Still, so far so good.

Here's where I'm getting stumped. At this point, I'm taking the data I'm receiving and assigning it to an object that can be used in components/views.

So I have something simple like:

```
this.data['DKJ39U4'] = JSON.parse(response);
```

But in my views, if I do this:

```
[(ngModel)]="service.data['DKJ39U4']"
```

I get an undefined error until the data shows up.

In a previous Angular 2 app, I would use a resolver but that worked really well for traditional GET/POST apps. This was easy as I had one service to get the data. Now I have multiple services.

I need to make the component wait (like a `Resolver`) for the `BaseDataService` to finish it's queries. But each component has its own dedicated service, so I can't, as far as I know, inject the component's service into a resolver inside my routing... can I?

Comment: I dont think you can, of course someone can illuminate us with an answer, however by wrapping your websocket server in an observable you can take advantage of the push mechanics, and "wait" for the new data. Can you post an excerpt of your service code?

Comment: I don't know how to make the resolve wait until say a boolean is true. If no one has responded, I'll try making a mini version of my code tomorrow.